# First column of author not properly alignment

Tags: horizontal-alignment

The problem is that the first column of authors is not centerd over the first column of text. The second column of author has the correct alignment. Se picture below.

[image]

The code I have been using you can see below

```
\documentclass[conference]{IEEEtran}
\usepackage{lipsum} 
\title{Some IEEE paper}

\author{
\IEEEauthorblockN{student Studentson, student Studentson, student Studentson}
\IEEEauthorblockA{School of Engineering\\
England Institute of Technology\\
London, England\\
(student1, student2, student3) @email.com}\\   
\and
\IEEEauthorblockN{Sir. John Doe}
\IEEEauthorblockA{School of Engineering\\
England Institute of Technology\\
London, England\\
email@school.com }\\                
}
\begin{document}
\maketitle


\begin{abstract}
\lipsum[1]
\end{abstract}

\lipsum[2-6]
\end{document}
```

Thanks!

Comment: I don't think either are aligned with the columns, it is just coincidental you have two author blocks and two columns, consider if you had 1 or 3 authors, it is just taking the two blocks and spacing them across the full page width,

Comment: The first problem is that the student names won't fit in `\columnwidth`.  You can force them into two columns using \parbox, or you could just lump Sir Doe in with the peons.